# Framework PHP com maior similaridade com CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, codeigniter, zend

Qual destes frameworks abaixo possuem maior similaridade com o CodeIgniter, para que eu possa ter a menor curva de aprendizado?

- Laravel
- CakePHP
- Zend

Comment: Essa pergunta é principalmente baseada em opiniões, e até um pouco ampla.

Comment: Codeigniter é simples, rápido de aprender, tem (ainda) uma comunidade ativa, mas esta ficando utrapasado. Laravel é rápido o aprendizado também, tem uma comunidade ativa. Symphony e Zend são mais 'fullstack' como chamam, a curva de aprendizado é maior, mas tem muito mais ferramentas, mas tem que ver a necessidade para o problema. Não vá usar um canhão para matar uma mosca. Todos esses tem uma boa documentação.

Comment: Já que alterou a pergunta (acho que melhorou) o mais parecido em meu ver é o Laravel e o Cake. O Zend e o Symphony são bem mais parrudos e a curva é bem maior. Mas se já conhece CI vai ficar bem mais fácil para aprender outros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo laravel ou cakephp, a linha de aprendizagem é bem menor que o zend.

Answer (score -2):

Recomendo o Zend Framework além ser um ótimo framework a empresa ainda fornece certificação em php.

Site: http://framework.zend.com/

Site da certificação: http://www.zend.com/services/certification/php-certification/

Comment: A questão era "curva de aprendizado" e não qualidade. Ele deixou isso claro na pergunta. Então Zend nem de longe, apesar de ser um **excelente** framework, não se encaixa nessa! =D

Comment: O Zend é possível sim aprender a curto prazo existe muitos matérias na internet que ensinam de forma simplificada.

Comment: 1º Depende das suas definições de **curto prazo**. Com uma semana no Laravel, eu já estava desenvolvendo coisas bem complexas. E não tinha background de PHP muito bom. 2º Não estou desmerecendo o FW. Fui bem enfático, no outro cometário: Zend é um **EXCELENTE** framework, mas o foco dele não é curva de aprendizado. Já o Laravel (devido a política de "limpeza de código", sendo ***limpeza*** adjetivo, e não verbo) tem uma curva de aprendizado muito boa, pra quem já vem do CodeIgniter. =D